# Mostrar la "sucursal" a la que pertenece a cada usuario desde una tabla pivot en laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo una serie de tablas `Grupo de marcas`, `Marcas`, `Sucursales`, pero específicamente en `Sucursales`, hice un tabla pivot con relacion al usuario ya que una sucursales puede tener muchos usuarios/empleados y un usuario (según su rol) 
puede tener varias sucursales, entonces necesito filtrar este ultimo por usuario, es decir que si mi usuario con id `10` ingresa a la aplicación web solo pueda ver sus sucursales, pero aqui es donde me he atorado ya que no encuentro la manera de traer todas las sucursales que coincidan con ese id del usuario

**Mi Modelo Sucursal**

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

**Mi Modelo de Usuario**

```
public function getRoleDisplayNames()
    {
        return $this->roles->pluck('display_name')->implode(', ');
    }

    public function sucursals()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Sucursal::class);
    }
```

Es tan facil y sencillo como hacer esto

```
 public function scopeAllowed($query)
    {
        if (auth()->user()->can('view', $this))
        {
            return $query; //Verficacion de si es administrador
        }
            return $query->where('id', auth()->id());
    }
```

Pero como lo hago con una tabla pivot de por medio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que tratas es de obtener todas las sucursales a las que pertenecen dicho usuario, debería bastar con hacer lo siguiente:

```
$userLogueado = auth()->id();
$data = User::with('sucursals')->findOrFail($userLogueado);
```

**Explicación**

- Asignas a una variable el usuario actualmente logueado, recuperando de este su `id`
- Puedes hacer uso de `eager loading`, para que en este caso al modelo `User` le recuperas todos sus registros relacionados por medio del método `sucursals`
- Como no te interesan todos los usuarios sino solamente las sucursales de un usuario; entonces debería alcanzar con hacer uso del método `findOrFail()` donde le pasas como valor la variable donde asignaste le `id` recuperado de la sesión actual